# Excel table running total formula based on two columns

Tags: excel

My Excel table has a deposits amount column and a payments amount column.  I need a formula for a running total column that will work even if I filter out some of the rows of data.

Comment: That answer works.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `subtotal` formula allows you to perform an aggregate operation against only the visible cells in the range.

Assuming your deposits start in cell A2 and payments in B2, you would enter the formula `=SUBTOTAL(109,$A$2:A2,$B$2:B2)` in C2 to start the running total. Use autofill to copy the formula down for each row.

`109` represents the `SUM` function. `$A$2:A2,$B$2:B2` are references to your deposit and payment columns. Autofill will dynamically resize the references when copied.

Assumption: Values in your payment column are negative. If not, use `=SUBTOTAL(109,$A$2:A2)-SUBTOTAL(109,$B$2:B2)` instead of the above formula.

[image]
[image]